# Why maximum range DATETIME(6) microsecond value is .499999?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need to define a datetime missing flag value other than a `NULL` flag.

About upper range `DATETIME(6)` value, [MySQL manual says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

> the range for DATETIME values is '1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59.499999'

Do you know why the max microsecond part value is `.499999` and not the much more intuitive `.999999` ?

`.999999` seems to be properly supported :

```
mysql> create temporary table _test (dt datetime(6));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into _test
     > values ('9999-12-31 23:59:59.499999'), ('9999-12-31 23:59:59.999998'), ('9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select all dt as i, dt + interval 1 microsecond as f from _test;
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| i                          | f                          |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 9999-12-31 23:59:59.499999 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.500000 |
| 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999998 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999 |
| 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999 | NULL                       |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It is probably a typo in the manual, because [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-syntax.html#:~:text=9999%2D12%2D31%2023%3A59%3A59.999999) they say: "9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the reasoning is that if you converted `9999-12-31 23:59:59.500000` to the nearest date-time without fractional seconds, the result would be out of range.  It would be bad from a semantic perspective.

Either way, it is clear that the `.499999` limit is not simply a typo.  It must have been a deliberate design decision.

> .999999 seems to be properly supported

Another way to interpret your test results is that the *specified* `.499999` limit is not correctly enforced by MySQL.

Comment: Yeah, thx (+1), `select all cast('9999-12-31 23:59:59.500000' as datetime);` gives `NULL`, open to other ideas

Comment: I'm not sure why you need other ideas.  (What is your use-case for using being to represent that last half second of the nominal range?)  But if you need to represent date-time values outside of the range, you could use a `BIGINT` or multiple `BIGINT`s.

Comment: Other idea: add a column with the datetime status flag (set, missing, missing2).

Comment: Ermm ... what is your use-case?  Frankly, I don't see the point in making your database schema / application complicated for the sake of representing one half second right at the end of the range.